# Chrome Extension Context Menu display link's url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, menu

I need to make a context menu option to search selected text or a link. I need to be able to display the text or link in the title of the context menu, but only selected text can appear. How can I display the link's url in the menu item title?

Code:

```
function searchGoogle(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText,
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Search %s", //I want to display selection AND link url
    contexts:["link", "selection"],
});
```

Comment: `contextMenus` provides only `onclick` handler which is fired *after* the user clicks your menu item. There's a slim chance to change the menu item title by having a content script with `document.addEventListener("mousedown", ...` which would post a message to background script where you can update the context menu item title accordingly. But I doubt the message will be delivered before the context menu is shown.

Comment: In recently Firefox, it is possible by inject scripts in every page (require access all sites permission), listen `contextmenu` events, post the text to background, update the menu item, call `menus.refresh()` to render the text. But `menus.refresh` is not available in Chrome. As a result, if you try to follow this idea, the text will not always be correct and there is no guarantee about it.